# Getting server settings from Microsoft Outlook 2010

Tags: email, outlook, exchange-server

I would like to read the mail server settings from Microsoft Outlook 2010.

Outlook has a mail account configured that uses a Microsoft Exchange server.

When I click "File", "Information", then "Account settings" Account" and then "Edit", I see the name of the exchange server and the user's login name (which is his email address).

I have also been told the password.

Additionally, a proxy is being used on this network.

Now I would like to configure a custom built mail program in such a way that it works like Microsoft Outlook 2010.

I'm using all parameters that I could find and which I have been told, but I don't see the SMTP or POP settings in Outlook 2010.

These are the settings that I can see within Outlook 2010:

[image]

How could I get the other settings like SMTP and POP settings?
Or am I totally wrong somewhere in my thinking?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, on the screenshot you have an Exchange account, not POP3/SMTP, so obviously you cannot extract any POP3/SMTP settings from there.

Account settings for all account types (Exchange, POP3/SMTP, IMAP4/SMTP, etc.) are stored in the profile sections accessible through Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi), namely through the [IOlkAccountManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/auxiliary/iolkaccountmanager) interface. You can play with that interface in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (click IOlkAccountManager button).
Profile sections are accessible directly through the registry, but the format is not documented.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes all Outlook accounts and their settings through the [RDOAccounts](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm) and [RDOAccount](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccount.htm) objects.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have read the following: "Office 365 and Exchange can (and do) provide the standard protocols for sending and reading email (SMTP, POP3, and IMAP)." So I was hoping I could see any of this info right in Outlook 2010. Do I really have to use your sophisticated tools to get this info?

Comment: Exchange 365 exposes smtp.office365.com as the SMTP endpoint. For an arbitrary Exchange server, there is no way to deduce the name of the outgoing SMTP server.

Comment: But an "arbitrary Exchange server" DOES expose an SMTP endpoint in any case?

Comment: Yes, but there is no way to retrieve its name. You would think that autodiscover XML would contain it, but it does not.